# Finding PDF of a function of a random variable

Tags: probability-theory

If $X$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, find the PDF of $Y = \cos^{-1} X$, $0 \le Y \le \pi/2$.

I got $F_Y(y) = P(Y \le y) = P(\cos^{-1} X \le y) = P(X \le \cos y) = F_X(\cos y) = \cos y$.

But the solution says $F_Y(y) = P(X \ge \cos y) = 1 - \cos y$

Why is it $P(X \ge \cos y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\cos^{-1} t$ is a *decreasing function* of $t$.

Thus, in your solution, you should have
$$P(\cos^{-1}X\le y)=P(X\ge \cos y).$$
So we get that the cdf of $Y$, for appropriate $y$, is $1-\cos y$, giving pdf $\sin y$.

**Remark:** Note that $\cos y$ could not be the cdf of anything, since it is a decreasing function.

Comment: So because $cos^{-1}$ is a decreasing function, I have to flip the inequality sign?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now.

Comment: You are welcome.